# Printing the screen (text-mode) to paper without drivers?

Tags: linux, terminal, printing

I am currently working on a machine that has entered Emergency Mode for CentOS 7.6.

To give myself a hard copy of logs and messages that appear on the screen (which are not from a file), I will take a photo from my phone.

Is there a way to redirect a copy of the text mode output sent to the screen to a printer without drivers?

Should I approach the situation differently? The goal is to get the output from the screen on paper after it's already on the screen, as I don't want everything and don't know what I want to save until after it's displayed.

Would this be something that a serial terminal would be used for to output to another computer and print from there?

Comment: Depending on the "emergency mode" used by your machine, you have a full shell access .. and if so  you can define a text controlled (special chars) printer maybe /dev/lp  & having a compatible printer  then you can redirect /dev/"yourconsole" to the printer ....   if you have a modern printer (usb) I do not think this is still possible without special drivers.